# JTable prevent all sorting

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Is it possible to prevent sorting all together on the JTable? Basically I don't want anything to happen when the user clicks the table header, and for the content to be in a static order.

Answer (score 4):

See [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSorter%28javax.swing.RowSorter%29):

> public void setRowSorter(RowSorter sorter)
>
> Parameters: `sorter` - the `RowSorter`; `null` turns sorting off

Answer (score 2):

> Basically I don't want anything to happen when the user clicks the table header, and for the content to be in a static order.

basically `JTable` haven't any Sorter, you have to remove codelines

```
- JTable#setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

- table.setRowSorter(sorter);

- custom Comparator added as MouseEvent to the JTableHeader
```

have look at and read [JTable tutorial about Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Answer (score 0):

The best and simple way to disable sorting when user clicks on any table header columns:

1. first you need to create a mouse click listener on the table header
2. inside of it make only mouse click left avaible (with SwingUtilities)
3. insert this line of code

   yourTableVariable.setRowSorter(null);

Practical example:

```
yourTableVariable.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() //here you make the click avaible ONLY on Table Header 
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) 
        {
            if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(arg0)) //here you select the mouse left click action 
            {
                yourTableVariable.setRowSorter(null); //here is disableing the sorting                  
            }
        }
    });
```